# Is setting my webserver to https, also securize my ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, https

Imagine I have a small webpage I browse in https with a signed certificate that load data with an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax(
    {
type:"POST",
url:"ressource/js/load_footer.php",
data:"page="+variable,
success:
    alert("poney");
    }
)
```

Can I assume that this ajax call is secure by https ? or does it communicate by http ?

Comment: Since it is a relative URL, it will use the protocol of the page it is executed in. But instead of asking, you could also have found this out easily yourself by just looking at the request in the net panel of your browser’s developer tools …

Comment: @CBroe I never notice it was that easy to see in firebug, I feel a bit ashamed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comment of my question:

> Since it is a relative URL, it will use the protocol of the page it is executed in. But instead of asking, you could also have found this out easily yourself by just looking at the request in the net panel of your browser’s developer tools … –  [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) [4 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986174/is-setting-my-webserver-to-https-also-securize-my-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment35103765_22986174)